# Magento site front end products info display breaking the site

Tags: php, magento, redirect, frontend

I am facing strange issue with my magento site. My website's front end is not working, but admin works fine.

It's showing nothing on front end even enabled errors and checked error log also, but nothing there. I am able to run index.php file but if works only before below line.

`Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`

After this nothing happens. No error message just browsers "connection reset...." message is displayed.

Anyone please help me to sort this out ? Please let me know if any more details I have to provide.

**Edit -**

After whole day R & D I got inventory is creating issue. anywhere where products ,products count and info related to them is displayed that  section causing this issue.

I have checked inventory in admin. Everything seems OK. can anyone guess now what can be issue ?

Comment: Why downvote ? Please write cause so I can take care for that from next time. Please

Comment: Nothing showing in var/logs - exception or system.log?

Comment: no, have checked no error.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error logs? It sounds like a PHP fatal exception.

Answer (score 1):

I remember when developing magento modules before. The culprit will always newly installed modules.

If you can't find anything from the logs try to disable one of the modules you just installed. Usually can be found at app/etc/modules/.

Good point is try to remember what you did last time before it shows the white screen. good luck!

Comment: There is no white screen. Just shows browser connection reset(mozilla), no data received (crome) etc according to browser type

Comment: As I said, check your PHP logs. **Something** will be logged somewhere.

Comment: Hi, Please check my edits on question. Let me know if you can help further ?

Comment: This is somewhat strange. I think you have to give us more info like @webnoob said.

I'm not quite sure if it's really in your bwosers cache. But if you can clear that too or running Chrome in Incognito mode and Firefox to a private mode then that might solve your issue?

Try to check your PHP logs again and see if theres something wrong about that line since PHP can't execute it. Can check that at /var/log/apache2/error.log (depends on your distro)

Comment: And I think it's good to check if you set php's error reporting to:
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
in your development machine.